# How to add commentator ("6th player")?

Tags: league-of-legends

I watched a few LoL matches [here](http://www.own3d.tv/game/League+of+Legends), and I saw that sometimes there is the "6th player" on both sides. He does not actually play, but rather enters the game, stays in the base and comments on the game. How can this be done? Is it a game feature, or is it some sort of a hack?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not a game feature nor a Hack.

The 6th player is a Mod/GM that can only be added by Riot staff; this player has the ability to see the map without fog of war and it is also capable off seeing both side stealth units.

Unfortunately I dont have a source to back up my statement, you can check on any of the matches where a 6th player is, at least one of them will have the name of a Riot employee, most likely *Phreak* and the game type play is a Draft Pick Custom Game.

Comment: hmm, but in matches I saw, the 6th player could only see his own team (the fog of war was still there).. and it did look a bit unofficial (for example, when voting for surrender there were 5 green/red bars, and one empty space.. which didn't look quite finished. or for example champion selection screen seemed weird, etc.). maybe there both official (riot), and some wild mods exist..

Comment: @pootzko Do you have a link to such match? Because I have only seen tournament matches, or Riot Events in which such 6th players are added. Maybe you saw a replay made with [League Replays](http://www.leaguereplays.com/)

Comment: hmm, I looked upon own3d.tv but I couldn't find any, sorry.. it was live streaming, not a replay.

Comment: I started a [Thread](http://www.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?p=8455791#post8455791) on the official forum, maybe a Red Post can reply accurately to this, however user comments might be enough

Comment: @pootzko: At the moment, Observer mode is bugged (when you use it, it crashes the game) which is why the casters couldn't remove the fog of war. But, yes, there are games where none of the casters work at Riot. Example: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-7BYI7Pi7TI